# PreparedStatement set value on multiple indexes

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have the problem with a prepared statement like this:

```
select ... from ... where xy = ? and foo = ? and bla = ?
```

can i set a string for every index? Otherwise i had to do

```
prep.setString(1, "bla");
prep.setString(2, "bla");
prep.setString(3, "bla");
```

or with for loop... but is there an elegant way? (beside adapt prepared statement or so?) may there is a method i dont know yet...

otherwise i create my own PreparedStatement class and extend it with this function

Comment: A for loop is quite succint and everybody knows what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How often do you really need to set the same value to several indexes in a `PreparedStatement` ? I wouldn't bother too much about looping once or twice for the few use-cases, where you actually have to do this...

**UPDATE**: Of course you could also re-write your SQL to something like this ;-)

```
select ... from ... where ? = all (
  select xy from ..
  union
  select foo from ..
  union
  select bla from ..
)
```

Then you'd only have one bind variable and a functionally equivalent SQL statement. I don't know about performance, though...

Comment: maybe but i thought it would be great to have... may i just use for loop^^

Comment: I'm pretty sure, someone will hate you eventually for having to maintain and bug-fix such a home-grown `PreparedStatement` ;-) They'd also hate you for using a SQL statement, such as the one I updated in my answer

Comment: they will hate me for the rest of the code anyway :D there are some things in there i realized later i made terrible wrong but other topic... i take the for loop!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think standard JDBC statements provide a solution to your problem. But you could create your own [`NamedParameterStatement`](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html) if you like named parameters.

Comment: Hmm, that named statement seems to be incomplete, see the comments: *FYI NamedParameterStatement is missing setNull method.*

Comment: @Lukas True, but you can easily modify the code and implement it yourself.

Comment: arg... my jdbc driver does not suppurt that -.-.-.- ok then back to for

Comment: @reox You can create the class yourself, the link contains a working implementation on page 2.